# Can I embed a message-properties-transformer in an outbound-endpoint?

Tags: mule

In an effort to clean up my mule message flow (visually), I'm trying to embed as many of the small transformations and such in my outbound endpoints, among other things.  Is it possible to embed a message-properties-transformer in an outbound endpoint?  According to this document, I thought it would be possible:  http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Endpoint+Configuration+Reference.

However, my flow seems to ignore the transformer when I nest it inside my endpoint like so:

```
    <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="...." port="...."
        path="...." method="GET"
        connector-ref="...." mimeType="application/json"
        contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP">
          <message-properties-transformer
            doc:name="Authorization">
            <add-message-property key="Authorization"
                value="....." />
          </message-properties-transformer>
          <response>
            <byte-array-to-string-transformer
                doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
          </response>
    </https:outbound-endpoint>
```

The transformer inside the  element works fine, but the message-properties-transformer does not.

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine. Both as transformer embedded inside the endpoint or as `transformer-refs`. I'm not sure why is being ignored. Which version of Mule are you using?

Perhaps if you use the `set-property` transformer rather than the deprecated `message-property-transformer`?